# Binomial coefficient congruence modulo $p^n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, binomial-coefficients, congruences

I am interested in the following congruence
$$\binom{ap^n}{bp^n}\equiv \binom{a}{b}\pmod{p^n}$$
I am aware that by some reference in a book the above it should actually hold modulo $p^{3n}$; the  reference in question is Zieve (1999) but could not find any trace of the paper.
I am also aware of the various generalizations of Lucas's theorem, but I do not see how it follows directly from one of them.
By standard tricks you can reduce the above to $$\binom{ap^n-1}{p^n-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{p^n}.$$

Comment: "I am also aware of the various generalizations of Lucas's theorem...": I suppose in particular you know about Granville's version for binomials mod prime powers?

Comment: Yes! But I do not see how it follows from that or maybe I am doing some computations wrong

Comment: For the standard congruence $\binom{2p}{p} \cong 2 \bmod p^3$, you have to impose $p \geq 5$. I would imagine there would be similar conditions, and perhaps more of them, needed for your more general statement.

Comment: Yes sorry! $p$ should be greater than  or equal to $5$

Comment: Could you give more details about what book has this reference?  I don't recall ever believing the stated congruence, but if I really said it was true in something I published then I'd like to write an erratum.  (I think I'm the only mathematician named "Zieve", so this appears to refer to me.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is false in general.

To show this, I will use the congruence
$$ \binom{p^k a}{p^k b} \equiv \binom{p^{k-1} a}{p^{k-1}b} \bmod p^{3k}$$
for $p\ge 5$ and $k \ge 1$.

This is originally due to Ljunggren and Jacobsthal in "On the divisibility of the difference between two binomial coefficients" in Skand. Mat.-Kongr., Trondheim 1949, 42-54 (1952). The case $k=1$ was established in the 19th century by Wolstenholme, with earlier works (with smaller exponents) by Cabbage and Lucas. See also Meštrović's survey mentioned in Ira Gessel's answer.

Let us consider the case $a=2$, $b=1$, $n=4$ of your congruence. You claim
$$\binom{2p^4}{p^4} \equiv \binom{2}{1} \bmod p^4.$$
Here is why it fails. By Ljunggren--Jacobsthal,
$$\binom{2p^4}{p^4} \equiv \binom{2p^3}{p^3} \bmod p^{12},$$
$$\binom{2p^3}{p^3} \equiv \binom{2p^2}{p^2} \bmod p^{9},$$
$$\binom{2p^2}{p^2} \equiv \binom{2p}{p} \bmod p^{6}.$$
In particular, we do know that
$$\binom{2p^4}{p^4} \equiv \binom{2p}{p} \bmod p^4.$$
Your congruence then implies that
$$\binom{2p}{p} \equiv 2 \bmod p^4.$$
Primes that satisfy this have a name: they are called Wolstenholme primes. The only such primes up to $10^9$ are 16843 and 2124679... One can show that $p$ is such a prime iff $p$ divides the numerator of the Bernoulli number $B_{p-3}$.

The proofs of Ljunggren--Jacobsthal suggest that for any given $a,b$, your congruence fails if $n > 3+\nu_p(\binom{a}{b}ab(a-b))$ where $\nu_p$ is the $p$-adic valuation.

---

For $n\le 3$ your congruence is true and directly follows from Ljunggren-Jacobsthal. Indeed, applying L-J with $k=1,2,3$ we have, in particular, that
$$\binom{ap^3}{bp^3} \equiv \binom{ap^2}{bp^2} \equiv \binom{ap}{bp} \equiv \binom{a}{b} \bmod p^{3}.$$

---

A more refined version of Ljunggren--Jacobsthal was proved by G. S. Kazandzidis:
$$ \binom{ap}{bp} \equiv \binom{a}{b} \bmod p^{3+\delta}$$
where $\delta=\nu_p(ab(a-b)\binom{a}{b})$.
This allows you to extend the range of validity $n \le 3$ if one of $a$, $b$, $a-b$ or $\binom{a}{b}$ is divisible by $p$.

This result (and variations) is proved in:

- "On a congruence and on a practical method for finding the highest power of a prime p which divides the binomial coefficient (AB)", Bull. Soc. Math. Grèce, N. Sér. 6, No. 2, 358-360 (1965).
- "Congruences on the binomial coefficients", Bull. Soc. Math. Grèce, N. Ser. 9, No. 1, 1-12 (1968).
- "On congruences in number-theory", Bull. Soc. Math. Grèce, N. Sér. 10, No. 1, 35-40 (1969).

All the mentioned papers are elementary. The modern treatment is a bit less so, but is more illuminating. Indeed, $p$-adic analysis can lead to a proof. See Chapter 7 of Alain M. Robert's book "A course in p-adic analysis" (GTM 198, Springer, 2000). The proof given there is based on the material in the paper "The Kazandzidis supercongruences. A simple proof and an application", Rend. Semin. Mat. Univ. Padova 94, 235-243 (1995), by Alain M. Robert and Maxime Zuber.

Some remarks:

- The congruence $\binom{ap^k}{bp^k} \equiv \binom{ap^{k-1}}{bp^{k-1}} \bmod p^{2k}$ has a combinatorial proof (as opposed to algebraic proofs mod $p^{3n}$). A reference for a combinatorial proof when the modulus is $p^n$ is Gian-Carlo Rota and Bruce Sagan's paper "Congruences derived from group action", Eur. J. Comb. 1, 67-76 (1980). I am not sure if this is the earliest reference of this kind of argument, though.
- There are various $q$-analogues of these $p$-adic congruences.
- Some of the above papers include also the cases $p=2$ and $p=3$ for which the exponent of $p$ in the modulus is slightly smaller.

Comment: Note that the congruence as stated in the OP is false: We have $\binom{ap^n}{bp^n} \equiv \binom{a p^{n-1}}{b p^{n-1}} \bmod p^{3n}$, but we only have $\binom{ap^n}{bp^n} \equiv \binom{a}{b} \bmod p^{3}$. Indeed, I checked $p=5$, and we have $\binom{50}{25} \equiv \binom{10}{5} \bmod 5^6$, but $\binom{50}{25} \equiv \binom{2}{1}$ only modulo $5^3$.

Comment: Thank you for the remark! This does not exclude the $p^n$. I would be happy with an example showing that is also false; in the example you had $n=2$ so mod 5^2 it works out

Comment: Thank you Ofir! I was aware of all those results but they do not help for this

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I've updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: @VladMatei I managed to prove above, using existing results, that your congruence fails for $n=4$, $a=2$ and $b=1$ and most primes up to $10^9$ (only 2 exceptions). For $n \le 3$ it holds by existing congruences you are familiar with.

Comment: Great! At least this shows that what I was trying to attempt for another problem clearly does not work. Thank you for looking into it

Comment: Do you have the Kazandzidis papers? The [EUDML links](https://eudml.org/doc/238547) are going nowhere right now...

Comment: @darijgrinberg No, sorry. Google does find the last one: "On congruences in number-theory", see https://hdml.di.ionio.gr/pdfs/journals/1014.pdf (note the link gives a security warning).

Comment: Ah, thank you for that one! Then https://hdml.di.ionio.gr/pdfs/journals/994.pdf is the second one. The scans are horrible and I can only download them with "wget --no-check-certificate", but it's a start...

Comment: I see, you guessed the filename from the EUDML broken link, cool. It could be that these two scans are all there is on-line (I am not sure I've seen the remaining 1965 paper with my own eyes, could be I became aware of it only through zbMath/MathSciNet, I can't recall exactly, these sites have a short review of it).

Answer (score 5):

A comprehensive account of these congruences can be found in Romeo Meštrović,*Wolstenholme's theorem: Its Generalizations and Extensions in the last hundred and fifty years (1862–2012)*,
https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1111.3057.

Comment: I checked all the statements there and none of them actually matches or maybe I am just not seeing it

Comment: The congruences that you stated are not correct; correct versions are given in Ofir Gorodetsky's answer. The related congruences in Meštrović's paper are (37)–(41); see also his Remark 21 on page 13.